# Joining two csv files into a key-value rdd using pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to combine two csv files with nothing in common (no key is common) into a key-value paired rdd using pyspark

Lets say A.csv has

```
a
b
c
```

and B.csv has

```
1
2
3
```

is there an option in pyspark to get an rdd by joining these two, like this

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
```

of course the number of rows in both the csv files should match. Is this something that is easy in pyspark or should this be done in regular python first. That is, do a nested loop of both the files and then make a tuple of tuples like ((a,1),(b,2)...) and then pass this to parallelize.

Comment: once you read your csv files as dataframes in spark you shouldn't make any assumptions on the order of the rows. So unfortunately you will have to do it before with regular python first.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is better to do the same using python first.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tool solution, showing the general principle, but not focusing on your specific data structures:

```
with file('A.csv','r') as f:
    a = f.read().split('\n')
with file('B.csv','r') as f:
    b = f.read().split('\n')
dic = dict(zip(a,b))
```

If you got more complex data structures, your should add a CSV parser (e.g. the  `csv` module from the standard Python library)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this for people who may need this in the future. I am just modifying the code from @sciroccorics slightly

```
import os

with open("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/a.csv",'r') as f:
    a = f.read().split('\n')
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/b.csv",'r') as f:
    b = f.read().split('\n')
tup = tuple(zip(a,b))
key_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(tup)
```

Notice the use of `tuple(zip(a,b))`